# Sorting an IList

Tags: c#

I have got a complete list of my brands to appear in my `DropDownBox`, however there appears to be no order (simply how they are input into the database) and I need to sort them into alphabetical order.

But it doesn't look like I can use the .Sort(); on an `IList` and there doesn't seem to be anything similar on `ILists` so I am at a bit of a loss, I have tried to convert the `IList` into a `List` and then using the `List.Sort()` method but I have had no luck with this as it just comes back unsorted again:

```
public void BrandListRetrieve()
{
    var factory = new BrandFactory();
    var customBool1State = 
          factory.ByCustomBoolean1(false, CoreHttpModule.Session);

    if (customBool1State != null)
    {
        var brandDropDown = CoreHttpModule
                                .Session
                                .CreateCriteria(typeof(Brand)).List<Brand>();

        foreach (Brand brand in brandDropDown)
        {
            this.Items.Add(brand.Name);
        }

        if (this.Items.Count < 0)
        {
            this.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Hello World", "Hello World"));
        }

        var brandList = brandDropDown as List<string>;

        if (brandList != null)
            brandList.Sort();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `this.Items`? Looks like you're sorting one list (`brandDropDown`) and expecting sort results to be appear in the second list (`this.Items`).

Comment: It's the collection of items in the list control :P

Comment: So, why should items collection in the list control be sorted, when you're sorting some *another* list, after populating items collection from this another list? Also, what type is `this.Items` of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should  try this;

```
foreach (Brand brand in brandDropDown.OrderBy(b => b.Name))
```

You can certainly **REMOVE** the following lines from your code;

```
        var brandList = brandDropDown as List<string>;

        if (brandList != null)
            brandList.Sort();
```

Comment: Hey Saj, that was just me messing around trying to get it to sort correctly with failed attempts. With your first line of code don't you mean


                foreach (Brand brand in brandDropDown)
                {
                    this.OrderBy(b => b.Name);
                }

Also using your original code I am told that it does not contain an OrderBy Method

Comment: No, he did mean what he typed :-)

Comment: No I don't mean that, you wan't to order the colection before you add it to the dropdownlist. and that's what my line of code does.

Comment: Ah I see, but I am still being told that the method does not exist on brandDropDown

Comment: @Hello: if you're using .NET 2, then it won't work because it doesn't contain LINQ. For .NET 3.5 and newer, add `using System.Linq;` at the beginning of your source file.

Comment: I think maybe you're missing some references, add a reference to System.Linq namespace

Comment: @groo I am using 3.5, I will try and use System.Linq but I think I might not be able to use this for a certain reason I will find out.

Comment: Update, I am able to use Linq we just haven't used it commonly so it now works perfectly, thank you very much for the help sir!

Answer (score -1):

it seems that you need to use brand.Sort() with Compare method. Try to read this manual http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx

Comment: No, `Sort` is an instance method of `List<T>`. OP has an `IList<T>`.